# Why can't I search specific things in file explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, find-in-files

Specifically,

When I'm in file explorer. I type in the search box in some folder, I type (1). And I want to find all the files with that little piece, and isolate them.

But when I type (1). open parentheses, one, close parentheses. It gives me the files with (1). But it also shows me files with _1 _ or just 1 in general.

Why doesn't it isolate what you've specifically typed in?

Comment: This may or may not help:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-explorer-search-syntax/6bde896b-e9f6-419d-b920-3b6ede0210e6

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes to tell the search that you want **literal** parentheses: `"(1)"`

Otherwise, unquoted parentheses mean a sub-query, like: `(draft OR final).docx`

I would use this kind of thing to find file duplicates: `~"*(1).txt"`

- `~`:match entire file name from the start
- `"`:double-quotes to allow for wildcards
- `*`: any file base name
- `.txt"`: and an exact end

The entire syntax documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#query-operators

Comment: Your search string is correct, but the syntax is not explained propertly. `~` tells search to allow wildcards *within* quoates, which are necessary for the parenthesees to be treated as literals. WIthout the tilde, even `*` and `?` are treated as literals as well.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

(1) Search from the Taskbar using the Indexed Search is often better to use for many things.

(2) Search from the Explorer bar works and does offer advanced settings.

(a) Constrain your text search with quotations marks to refine your search.

I use quotation marks frequently.

(b) Once a search term has been entered, click on Search in the ribbon and further constrain your search.

Description attached here.

[image: Windows File search settings]

**Note:** For all frequent Windows searches, make sure you have Indexing enabled and have your common locations indexed. This will help find things much faster.

[image: Index Locations]